# Using `dd` command to test performance on different partitions

Tags: linux, centos, hard-drive

I'm trying to setup a web application on the Azure Preview Portal. I've created a Linux Centos 6.2 machine from the Azure VM gallery and attached some disks to it.

`df -h` gives me this:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup-lv_root
                       28G  4.2G   22G  16% /
tmpfs                 1.7G     0  1.7G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             485M   94M  366M  21% /boot
/dev/sdb1             133G  188M  126G   1% /mnt/resource
/dev/sdc1              40G  176M   38G   1% /mnt/datadrive
```

`sdb1` and `sdc1` are both storage drives. `sdb1` is the default one created when you create the machine and `sdc1` was attached by me as another 40GB drive.

I want to test the performance of each drive and compare it with the boot drive (that is probably `sda1`).

I've tried using `dd` for it:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/tmp/zero bs=1k count=100k // test for sda1
dd if=/dev/sdb1 of=/tmp/zero bs=1k count=100k // test for sdb1
dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/tmp/zero bs=1k count=100k // test for sdc1
```

But I'm not sure if it actually does the test in different partition in each run. Is this a correct way to test the read/write of different partitions ? thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While dd can be a useful tool it's also important to remember the possibility that you're testing a file that has already been cached.  In NFS environments we've gone so far as to unmount and remount partitions between test iterations to make sure we were definitively hitting the server rather than relying on something local.

Answer (score 1):

You would better use some more specific tools for test disk speeds, like [bonnie++](http://www.coker.com.au/bonnie++/) or [iometer](http://www.iometer.org/). They will give you more detailed information than a pure dd.

Answer (score 0):

DD can provide some insight in this fashion, however the method that you are using can be improved on.

You need to be sure that either the source or destination doesn't have a physical drive backing it, otherwise you potentially get performance characteristics which include both elements.

My suggestion would be to use the following commands to test performance.

With the destination disk mounted under /mnt/sdb1

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/mnt/sdb1/image_file bs=1k count=...
```

With the source disk unmounted.

```
dd if=/dev/sdb1/image_file of=/dev/null bs=1k count=...
```

This should create a large file consisting of only the null character. This is fairly safe to perform on any disk, including your root if you have the space.